# Uncaught Type Error: Undefined is not a function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In the script section, i get the Uncaught Type Error: Undefined is not a function JavaScript error. What might be wrong? I checked to see if the .js files have been called, and everything is in order.

```
@model Crux.Models.Question
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Create";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<link href="~/Content/jquery.tagit.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/tag-it.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Question</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.question, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.question)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.question)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="hashtags" class="control-label col-md-2">Tags</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input id="hashtags" name="hashtags" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
}
<div>
  @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#hashtags").tagit({
      allowSpaces: false,
      singleField: true,
      singleFieldNode: $('#hashtags'),
      availableTags: ["c++", "java", "php", "javascript", "ruby", "python", "c"]
    });
  }); 
</script>
```

It gives the error on line: `$("#hashtags").tagit({`

Comment: What's the raw rendered source look like? I can't think of a reason, but maybe .NET is parsing out your id tag from the html?

Comment: What is `jquery-ui.js`? There is no version number so it this a custom build file? Does it include the necessary jquery ui components (Core, Widget, Position, and Autocomplete)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: it's built in. was already in the MVC 5.

Comment: It should have a version number. For MVC 4 its `jquery-ui-1.8.20.js`. (I don't have MVC 5 but current is 1.11.2). And don't use `min` versions (you can't debug it!). Use bundling so you have the full versions in debug mode and minified versions in production.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i get the same without the version when i download right from the page.

Comment: Perhaps its been changed for MVC 5? Do you have any scripts in the `_Layout` page

Comment: @HariharShankar, Just loaded jquery ui using nuget and got `jquery-ui-1.11.2.js`

Comment: what did you type in nugget? Install-Package jQuery?

Comment: In VS, `Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages ..` and search `jquery ui`.

Answer (score 0):

I was clashing jQuery by loading it three different times. from bundles and the page itself. removed all the links, and finally worked.